# Regex to match string with and without special/accented characters?

Tags: php, regex

Is there a regular expression to match **a specific string with and without special characters**? Special characters-insensitive, so to speak.

Like `céra` will match `cera`, and vice versa.

Any ideas?

Edit: I want to match specific strings with and without special/accented characters. Not just any string/character.

**Test example:**

```
$clientName   = 'céra';
$this->search = 'cera';

$compareClientName = strtolower(iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $clientName));
$this->search      = strtolower($this->search);

if (strpos($compareClientName, $this->search) !== false)
{
    $clientName = preg_replace('/(.*?)('.$this->search.')(.*?)/iu', '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span>$3', $clientName);
}
```

Output: `<span class="highlight">céra</span>`

As you can see, I want to highlight the specific search string. However, **I still want to display the original (accented) characters** of the matched string.

I'll have to combine this with [Michael Sivolobov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023364/2187401) somehow, I guess.

I think I'll have to work with a separate `preg_match()` and `preg_replace()`, right?

Comment: `é` isn't a special char, it's an accented letter.

Comment: I'm trying to match specific strings, not just any string/character. Sorry for the confusion. I updated my question.

Comment: I updated my answer aswell based on @Michael Sivolobov suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `\p{L}` pattern to match any letter.

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

You have to use the `u` modifier after the regular expression to enable unicode mode.

Example : `/\p{L}+/u`

**Edit :**

Try something like this. It should replace every letter with an accent to a search pattern containing the accented letter (both single character and unicode dual) and the unaccented letter. You can then use the corrected search pattern to highlight your text.

```
function mbStringToArray($string)
{
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    while($strlen)
    {
        $array[] = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
        $string = mb_substr($string, 1, $strlen, "UTF-8");
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    }
    return $array;
}

// I had to use this ugly function to remove accents as iconv didn't work properly on my test server.
function stripAccents($stripAccents){
    return utf8_encode(strtr(utf8_decode($stripAccents),utf8_decode('àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ'),'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY'));
}

$clientName = 'céra';

$clientNameNoAccent = stripAccents($clientName);

$clientNameArray = mbStringToArray($clientName);

foreach($clientNameArray as $pos => &$char)
{
    $charNA =$clientNameNoAccent[$pos];
    if($char != $charNA)
    {
        $char = "(?:$char|$charNA|$charNA\p{M})";
    }
}

$clientSearchPattern = implode($clientNameArray); // c(?:é|e|e\p{M})ra

$text = 'the client name is Céra but it could be Cera or céra too.';

$search = preg_replace('/(.*?)(' . $clientSearchPattern . ')(.*?)/iu', '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span>$3', $text);

echo $search; // the client name is <span class="highlight">Céra</span> but it could be <span class="highlight">Cera</span> or <span class="highlight">céra</span> too.
```

Comment: Is the OP really wanting to match _any_ letter? Or rather to match `é|e` when specifying only `e` for example?

Comment: @w3d This. I want to match specific strings with and without special (accented) characters. I updated my question.

Comment: The example I gave will match céra and cera.

Comment: @Kethryweryn Indeed, but I'm searching for specific strings. Like `substr()`, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Kethryweryn: Yes, but it will also match `abcd`, which is not desirable. As I understand it, the OP is wanting a generalised/simple way of matching `c[ée]ra` only, but for any word and any accent - not quite so simple.

Comment: Edited a typo `$pos => &$char`. And changed a variable `$charNA = $clientNameNoAccent[$pos];` (String where Array expected). Nice piece of code for direct use, thanks!

Comment: Btw, `iconv()` didn't work for me either, it returned something like "c'era". Any thoughts on this behaviour maybe?

Comment: @jlmmns You can use strings as arrays. You can't foreach on a string as it isn't an iterator, but you can access any char as if it was an array (well, it IS an array in C). For iconv(), I've read it was a bad iconv library on another stackoverflow question. Didn't try to hard to find the cause though, I've had problems with iconv each time I had to use it so...

Comment: For your edit suggestion, this isn't a typo. It allows the foreach to access the real value and not a copy. If you remove it, you won't really change the value of $char, and you will have to either copy the new array or change the value with $clientNameArray[$pos] instead of just changing $char.

Comment: Woops, my bad. Haven't seem them used like that before. Apologies!

Comment: Hmm, I didn't notice it at first, but the regex seems to highlight the whole string, instead of only the matched part. `(?:M|m|m\p{M})ichael (?:C|c|c\p{M})era`, when searching for either "michael" or "cera".

Comment: Nevermind, I had to switch $clientName and $search for my test case.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know is there some accent or another mark on some letter you can check it by matching pattern `\p{M}`

**UPDATE**

You need to convert all your accented letters in pattern to group of alternatives:

E.g. `céra -> c(?:é|e|e\p{M})ra`

Why did I add `e\p{M}`? Because your letter é can be one character in Unicode and can be combination of two characters (e and grave accent). `e\p{M}` matches **e with grave accents** (two separate Unicode characters)

As you convert your pattern to match all characters you can use it in your `preg_match`

Answer (score 3):

As you marked in one of the comments, you don't need a regular expression for that as the goal is to find specific strings. Why don't you use `explode`? Like that:

```
$clientName   = 'céra';
$this->search = 'cera';

$compareClientName = strtolower(iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $clientName));
$this->search      = strtolower($this->search);

$pieces = explode($compareClientName, $this->search);

if (count($pieces) > 1)
{
    $clientName = implode('<span class="highlight">'.$clientName.'</span>', $pieces);
}
```

**Edit:**

If your `$search` variable may contain special characters too, why don'y you `translit` it, and use `mb_strpos` with `$offset`? like this:

```
$offset = 0;
$highlighted = '';
$len = mb_strlen($compareClientName, 'UTF-8');
while(($pos = mb_strpos($this->search, $compareClientName, $offset, 'UTF-8')) !== -1) {
    $highlighted .= mb_substr($this->search, $offset, $pos-$offset, 'UTF-8').
         '<span class="highlight">'.
         mb_substr($this->search, $pos, $len, 'UTF-8').'</span>';
    $offset = $pos + $len;
}
$highlighted .= mb_substr($this->search, $offset, 'UTF-8');
```

**Update 2:**

It is important to use `mb_` functions with instead of simple `strlen` etc. This is because accented characters are stored using two or more bytes; Also always make sure that you use the right encoding, take a look at this for example:

```
echo strlen('é');
> 2

echo mb_strlen('é');
> 2

echo mb_internal_encoding();
> ISO-8859-1

echo mb_strlen('é', 'UTF-8');
> 1

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
echo mb_strlen('é');
> 1
```

Comment: I think working with string positions is the only easy way, for maintaining the original characters. I'll look into this, thanks!

Comment: If you think this answers your original question, don't hesitate to mark it as the accepted answer :)

Comment: btw I added another update that cover important caveat related to multibyte characters

Comment: I'll come back to this answer. :) Thanks for the info on `mb_`!

Comment: I'm currently using [Kethryweryn's updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19023200/2187401), since it's a bit better formatted and easier to read/implement. But I'm going to try your answer as well, and see what works best.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch04_09.htm), `POSIX equivalence class` is for matching characters with the same collating order that can be done by below regex:

```
[=a=]
```

This will match `á` and `ä` as well as `a` depending on your locale.

Comment: But aren't the POSIX regular expression syntax (and associated `ereg()` functions) deprecated as of PHP 5.3?

Comment: @w3d Yes but PCRE even supports all of the POSIX named character classes as well.

Comment: In what version of PHP? Is there a trick to enabling this? I get: "Warning: preg_match() Compilation failed: POSIX collating elements are not supported..."